# JDBC - Error in communication (MySQL + Eclipse)

Tags: jdbc

I am getting an error Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on localhost:3306? i have written a jdbc program using type 4 jdbc driver and i want to perform a delete operation  and the ide is eclipse.
code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String cs="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/account_db";
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(cs,"root",<password>);
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from empde emp_id=?");
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
while(true)
{
    System.out.println("enter the emp_id :");
    int ac_id=s.nextInt();
    ps.setInt(1,emp_id);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("one emp_id is deleted:");
    System.out.println("one more emp_id?(yes/no)");
    String choice=s.next();
    if(choice.equals("no"))
    System.out.println("empde is exit");
    break;
}
ps.close();
con.close();
```

Error detected:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on localhost:3306? at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.init(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what error you got,could u briefly explain ?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on localhost:3306?
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.init(Unknown Source)

Comment: it may be because of mysql , did you check your mysql running on local host (port 3306)

Comment: yes i just checked the connection and it says that the connection parameters are correct

Comment: and i tried executing the same program using cmd prompt and it gave  error stating that java.lang.no classdef if i have to set the classpath please tell me how to set

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of using an old `MySQL Connector/J` JDBC driver. I'm assuming that you've the latest MySQL installed and you're trying to connect using an older version of MySQL Connector jar.

You might want to update your driver from the [MySQL drivers download website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html/)

Answer (score 0):

if you compile the java code from cmd prompt means you need to set java path before you compiling  by this way.

```
set path=(drivein which java is stored):\program files\java\jdk(version)\bin;
ex: set path=C:\program files\Java\jdk1.6.0\lib;
```

once you set the environment variable means you don't need to set the java path for each     and every time just see the link for how to set environment variable .

http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-classpath.shtml

and also see the link when using mysql you need to set CLASSPATH see the link

http://java.blogs.webucator.com/2010/07/05/java-database-connectivity-jdbc-basics-using-mysql/